# elasticsearch-py driver is not filtering data properly when aggregating

Tags: elasticsearch, pyelasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I faced a weird with elasticsearch python drivers and would like if someone can explain it to me! The below code works directly from `cURL` but doesn't work with `python-requests` or `elasticsearch-py`, strangely, it works when I switch to `pyelasticsearch` library! The details are:

I have a type called `MY_TYPE` that has a nested object `MY_NESTED_FIELD` and a child document `MY_CHILD_TYPE`. I'm trying to do term facet aggregation on the nested attributes based on filters applied to the `MY_TYPE` and `MY_CHILD_TYPE` types. The query looks like

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "has_child": {
          "query": {
            "range": {
              "CHILD_FIELD": {
                "gte": 0.5
              }
            }
          },
          "type": "MY_CHILD_TYPE"
        }
      }
    }
  },    

  "aggs": {
    "aggregation_results": {
      "aggs": {
        "boards": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "MY_NESTED_FIELD.KEY",
            "size": 100
          },
          "aggs": {
            "MY_RANGES": {
              "range": {
                "ranges": [
                  {
                    "to": 0.5,
                    "from": 0
                  },
                  {
                    "to": 0.8
                    "from": 0.5
                  }
                ],
                "field": "MY_NESTED_FIELD_PATH.VALUE"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "nested": {
        "path": "MY_NESTED_FIELD_PATH"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this query against elasticsearch directly (using `cURL` or `head` plugin) it filters the parent and returns aggregations based on correct results. However, when I try it from the python script, it runs successfully but returns wrong data (it returns facets from all the documents without applying the filter)

I have tried:

- cURL: *Works!*
- ElasticSearch's HEAD plugin: *Works!*
- python-requests version 2.8.1: **Did not work!**
- elasticsearch-py api versions 1.4.0 and 2.1.0: **Did not work!**
- pyelasticsearch version 1.4: *Works!*

The code snippets for elasticsearch-py is:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es   = Elasticsearch('HOST:PORT')
data = es.search(index='INDEX_NAME', doc_type='MY_TYPE', body=payload, q='*:*', size=0)
```

When using python-requests, the code was:

```
import requests
url = 'http://ES_HOST:ES_PORT/ES_INDEX/ES_TYPE/_search'
params = {'size':0, 'q':'*:*'}
data   = requests.post(url, params=params, data=json.dumps(payload)).json()
```

My elastic search version is:

```
{
  "version": {
    "number": "1.4.4",
    "build_hash": "c88f77ffc81301dfa9dfd81ca2232f09588bd512",
    "build_timestamp": "2015-02-19T13:05:36Z",
    "build_snapshot": false,
    "lucene_version": "4.10.3"
  }
}
```

So my questions are:

1. Is this the best way to write this query?
2. Is there an explanation for why elasticsearch-py is acting strangely?
3. Is there a fix for this on elasticsearch-py?

Comment: would you please include a code snippet using "python-requests"?

Comment: @AnasMe I added a the sample code using python-requests

Comment: Why do you have `q=*:*` in your parameters?

Comment: @fabianvf sometimes I give the client the ability to add additional filters with the lucene syntax (in addition to standard DSL syntax)

I noticed in pyelasticsearch, I could use either the 'q=QUERY' or the DSL syntax (but not both).

Do you think it's related to my problem?

Comment: I would suggest trying without it. I'm not sure what the interaction between your filtered query and the query string match all query would be. It may make no difference. I would suggest trying to integrate it into your larger query using the DSL though, if it's not too difficult.